# Not exact coordinates plotting matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting coordinates in order to have same result of this pitch (plotting only green X)[image]

But my result is not exact, points are shifted up and right:[image]

This is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

im = plt.imread('statszone_football_pitch.png')
implot = plt.imshow(im, aspect='auto')
xlim, ylim = plt.xlim(), plt.ylim()

dpi=90


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(620/dpi, 579/dpi), dpi=dpi)
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frame_on=False)
#ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
#ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.imshow(im, interpolation='none')

y, x = np.genfromtxt('coordinate_tackle_success.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x,y, "o")
plt.xlim(xlim)
plt.ylim(ylim)

plt.savefig('tackles.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

In [`ax.imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow), you could add the `extent` argument to influence the placement of the image.

Comment: How do i set extent in this case?

Comment: You add it as a named argument to the `imshow` call. See the documentation that I linked to.

Comment: Well using the size of the pitch as extent ([0,760,0,520]) I have bad positioning as before